# Why TypeScript can't narrow the type of field in assignment

Tags: typescript, typeerror

I want to update some string fields of an object:

```
interface Obj {
    a: string;
    b: string;
    d: Date;
}

const fields: (keyof Obj)[] = ['a', 'b'];
const obj: Obj = {
    a: 'c',
    b: 'd',
    d: new Date(),
}

fields.forEach((field) => {
    if (typeof obj[field] === 'string') {
        obj[field] = field;
    }
});
```

However. the compiler complains about `obj[field]` ***inside*** the conditional:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & Date'.  
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string & Date'.  
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.(2322)
```

We're good here since I already made sure that we're dealing with strings only. And if I run this code it actually works - see it at [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWyDeAoZQ5OALmQGcwpQBzAbgKPTMupHscIBMyAROSAwC+ePAgD2ISshjAIAGy7kyACgDWEAJ7iYaLAEoA2gF1kAXmSGA5HCsAaZFfRXjDCVLDJxWMhmwX8ImIyKwR7TmRmRy5woJ5kEAgAd2R+SBV9OzwRPFkFJQA6GHEoAFFEAAsVFTzFfXMAPlwI4F0VME0ABwgdLyxDWq5TMxHHVloresCgom9MAblFYZlFrgYgkSF9BjFJcnF5CAL5cRoVOe2gA). Still, an error is reported.

Why is that and how to get rid of it?

Comment: It's a mixture of a bunch of things, most notably [ms/TS#10530](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10530) and [ms/TS#32693](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32693), and even trying to fix it with generics runs into some limitations. You can just use a type assertion and move on [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mAPqZN), or if you want something a little safer or reusable you could write a custom type guard function [like this](https://tsplay.dev/mbye9N).  Neither is great, though.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Comment: @jcalz: your comment is pretty thorough. If you'd like to convert it into answer I'd gladly accept it